# Error: Can't set headers after they are sent Braintree

Tags: node.js, braintree

I am currently working on an admin panel for this website I am creating, so I am able to accept payments via Braintree but I need to implement the ability to retrieve a customers transactions but once a header is sent it sends just one of them and not the whole thing. Is it possible to combine the json to an array so it will send in the one header?

CODE:

```
router.get('/:cid/test', function(req, res) {
  var stream = gateway.transaction.search(function (search) {
  search.customerId().is(req.params.cid);
  }, function (err, response) {
    response.each(function (err, transaction) {
      return res.render('admin/test', {transaction: transaction});
    });
  });
});
```

This is solely following the Braintree documentation and I know exactly why the error occurs. Any help is really appreciated and I am terrible at explaining so if you need to know more information please give me a holler!

UPDATE: So, I figured I would explore another method and I noticed the 'response' gives back an array of ids. So I will just use EJS to loop through all those and then have a seperate page for each transaction.

Comment: If it could be converted to an array I could definitely loop over it with EJS.

Comment: Braintree people hang out here, last I saw, but their tech support by email was pretty good last time I used it. You should try that. Their documentation is horrible as you have found out.

Comment: They do have good email support but unfortunately they are closed for the New Years and yes it's horrid lol.

Comment: Are you using Express? I don't think this is a problem with Braintree, but with Express (or whatever you may use instead), so I think that information is vital.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I work for Braintree :)*

As Robert noted, you can only call `res.render` (or any of the response methods that `end` the request) once per request (hence the error from express).

Unfortunately, you cannot treat `response` as an array, so you will need to use
one of the two documented ways of interacting with [`search responses`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/searching/search-results/node#stream-responses). I personally prefer the streams approach because it is clearer:

```
app.get('/stream', function (req, res) {
  var transactions = []
  var transactionStream = gateway.transaction.search(function (search) {
    search.customerId().is(req.params.cid);
  })

  transactionStream.on('data', function (transaction) {
    transactions.push(transaction)
  })

  transactionStream.on('error', function () { /* handle errors */ })

  transactionStream.on('end', function () {
    res.json({transactions: transactions});
  })
})
```

Alternately, you can use the `ids` property of `response` to compare the transactions array that you build from `each` to know when to end the request:

```
app.get('/calback', function (req, res) {
  var transactionStream = gateway.transaction.search(function (search) {
    search.customerId().is(req.params.cid);
  }, function (err, response) {
    var transactions = []
    response.each(function (err, transaction) {
      transactions.push(transaction)
      if (transactions.length === response.ids.length) {
        res.json({transactions: transactions});
      }
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only render one response per route. So you can only call this once and not in a loop:

```
res.render('admin/test', {transaction: transaction}); });
```

You can use the each method to iterate through the response and build up a result:

```
var transactions =[];
response.each(function (err, transaction)   { transactions.push(transaction) });
return res.render('admin/test', {transaction: transactions});
```

That would work if the each method is synchronous. If it's not (and Nick would know), use the solution below.

Comment: Unfortunately `response` is not an array here, it is an object with an `each` method (is this confusing, yes :) )